# How to write SQL translateable linq code that groups by one property and returns distinct list

Tags: linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I want to change code below to be sql translateable because now i get exception.

Basicallly i want list of customers from certain localisation and there could be more than one customer with the same CustomerNumber so i want to take the one that was most recently added.
In other words - distinct list of customers from localisation where "distinct algorithm" works by taking the most recently added customer if there is conflict.

The code below works only if it is client side. I could move `Group By` and `Select` after `ToListAsync` but i want to avoid taking unnecessary data from database (there is include which includes list that is pretty big for every customer).

```
var someData = await DbContext.Set<Customer>()
                .Where(o => o.Metadata.Localisation == localisation)
                .Include(nameof(Customer.SomeLongList))
                .GroupBy(x => x.CustomerNumber)
                .Select(gr => gr.OrderByDescending(x => x.Metadata.DateAdded).FirstOrDefault())
                .ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

No way. GroupBy has limitation: after grouping only Key and Aggregation result can be selected. And you are trying to select `SomeLongList` and full entity `Customer`.

**Best answer:**

It can be done by the SQL and `ROW_NUMBER` Window function but without `SomeLongList`

**Workaround:**

It is because it is not effective

```
var groupingQuery = 
   from c in DbContext.Set<Customer>()
   group c by new { c.CustomerNumber } into g
   select new 
   {
      g.Key.CustomerNumber,
      DateAdded = g.Max(x => x.DateAdded)
   };

var query = 
   from c in DbContext.Set<Customer>().Include(x => x.SomeLongList)
   join g in groupingQuery on new { c.CustomerNumber, c.DateAdded } equals 
                              new { g.CustomerNumber, g.DateAdded }
   select c;

var result = await query.ToListAsync();
```

Comment: so should i just forget about it and filter it client side if the workaround isn't more effective?

Comment: SQL is the best way. Filtering on the client side is the worst idea - whole table will be populated. Better to use workaround.

Comment: I really disagree with your classifications. If the *best* answer is without some part of the requirement, then it's not an answer, right? Then what is the answer? Or the *workaround* is actually the answer? Then why calling it *workaround* if it *is the answer*?

Comment: It is your point of view. For me workaround is a bad SQL Server  resources usage. Original question is, how to write this in LINQ. I called resource consuming LINQ query as a workaround.